# Help with the boss Tabuu on SSBB

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

I'm trying to finish the Subspace Emissary in Super Smash Bros. Brawl. I've been stuck on the boss battle against Tabuu (in normal and easy modes). I know the secret to one of his moves, the one with the energy blasts, you have to sidestep or roll. Although I can never seem to get the timing correct, or even perform the correct maneuver. I had a friend who managed to dodge that attack several times by pressing random buttons, but that hardly helps because it never works for me.

I've gotten his health bar a little past two thirds of the way before, but it was that repeated move that took me out. Recognizing his other moves and dodging them are fairly easy, but that single move always kills me. If anyone had any tips, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: The title isn't really descriptive of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any character that has strong air attacks and can stay in the air long enough to avoid [Tabuu](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Tabuu)'s many attacks that hit along the ground should be good for fighting him. Be careful when using exceptionally light characters though, because they also die faster when being hit by these attacks.

In order to avoid the Off Waves attack, you need to [spot dodge](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Sidestepping) by holding the shield button and pressing down on the joystick while standing on the ground.

You can view strategies for fighting Tabuu in these YouTube videos. I've listed the times when Off Waves happens, so you can see what timing you need to dodge the waves:

- [SSBB: Final Stage Tabuu beaten by only Zelda SSE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvLqcoJekKg) (Off Waves at 2:02 and 3:13)
- [Super Smash Bros Brawl, Pit vs Tabuu on Intense mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvmGgLAYL_0) (Off Waves at 1:24, 2:44, and 4:04)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure of which buttons to use, and the videos should help a lot. I'll try it out and get back to you as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Characters who can stay in the air for a long time while dealing decent damage are good against Tabuu. I used Kirby, Meta Knight, and Pit for sure, probably Jigglypuff (although his aerial offense isn't that hot); I don't remember who else. Conversely, characters who have a hard time staying in the air will have a hard time attacking Tabuu (Ganon and Ike are especially bad since they fall so fast), since he doesn't spend a lot of time on the ground. Even with characters like Kirby and Pit who can mostly fly, it's still not easy! Keep at it.

As you discovered, the Off Waves, where he goes into the background and opens his wings with massive blasting, is by far his toughest attack to avoid. I think I mostly just died to it; if you play well enough that this is the only attack that kills you, you should beat him on your 5th character, leaving you one death of margin. Characters who can fly for a long time (see above) will have an easier time air-dodging this attack than trying to sidestep it, because the air-dodge input is a lot easier to do than sidestep (at least for me). Bowser is possibly worth mentioning here, because his air dodge and sidestep are both slightly longer in duration than most characters, and even if you botch the timing, he's so heavy that Off Waves might not actually kill him like it's supposed to.

Most of Tabuu's other attacks can be dodged just by flying for a long time, which is why I picked the flying characters.

Comment: I haven't thought of trying Bowser before, and he does deal a lot of damage with each hit. About finishing him on my 5th character, I'm only good at dodging I suppose, so by the time he has used the Off Wave attack five times, I haven't made much progress on his health. I'll look into using Bowser, and his air dodge. Thank for the fast reply.

Answer (score -2):

Using Kirby's rock attack, (though dealing no damage to him whatsoever) does not work, you still go flying  off the stage with 0%! As stated before high-flying characters would be good against a boss like Tabuu. A strong character would be good too so I suggest Meta Knight with multiple recovery moves and multiple jumps. A character like Yoshi would be considerable due to his high jumping ability as well as Lucas and Ness but not recommended since all three have little recovery after that.

Comment: Meta Knight is "SS" tier because he is really strong against *other players*. This tier list (the source of which you should be [linking](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Tier_list)) is not necessarily accurate for the Subspace Emissary mode.

Comment: Um thats not exactly where I got the roster...actually, I just looked it up on Google. Besides how do you link?

Comment: In answers, you can link by clicking the small chain icon and entering the URL in the prompt. In other places, such as here in the comments, you can put in [ link description here ]( url.goes.here.com ), without the spaces.

Comment: Oh and yeah when Tabuu opens his wings it **ALWAYS** kills that is the whole idea behind it (in [this](https://youtu.be/3QTZm4-jDIw?t=2758) cutscene) at least in SSE not Boss Battles.

Answer (score -2):

i will reccomend practice, anticipating the attacks, also using side dodge in the butterfly wings of death, jumping onto the head and attacking him when laser eyes of death, crouching when fish arrow of death except for meta knight, I think you can avoid the dragon blaster just fine, (just stay on the ground then jump up a lot when coming) Im not sure about the trap bracket, or the whip, though